# Why when I use it as resource it crashes?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a DataGridTextColumn, and wanted to set the text in the middle, I did this  XAML :

```
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Smooth" Binding="{Binding Smoothing}">
             <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
             </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
```

That worked fine. I have a lot of DataGridTextColumn, so I wanted to extract the style as a resource. Which looks like :

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox"  x:Key="TextBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>


</UserControl.Resources>
```

and I do this for my GridItem :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Smooth" Binding="{Binding Smoothing}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TextBoxStyle}"/>
```

I actually get a crash complaining when checking the TargetType. Any ideas why the first parts work but not the second part?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of crash? Do you get an errormessage? Compiletime or runtime?

Comment: It seems that If I use TextBlock instead of TextBox that works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle` should be targetted to a `TextBlock` and **NOT `TextBox`**.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TextBlockStyle">
     <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
 </Style>
```

Your **`DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle`** should be the one that targets a `TextBox` (if your data grid or column is editable)

(Simply because readonly text cell has TextBlock and text cell in edit mode has a TextBox in it)

Comment: Thanks @AngelWPF . Just change VerticalContentAlignment to VerticalAlignment :)